# How to close activity from ASyncTask?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I start `ASyncTask` from the `Activity`:

```
public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this, consumer, provider).execute();
    }
```

Then, depending on result of ASyncTask execution I should either close this `PrepareRequestTokenActivity` activity on not.

(Result is known to `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onPostExecute you simple use your this variable to execute finish().

in your constructor keep your activity reference 
and call finish() in onPostExcecute method

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623823/finish-the-calling-activity-when-asynctask-completes and suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ((Activity)context).finish();

Answer (score 3):

If you're working from within `onPostExecute`, and you're `asyncTask()` class is internal to your activity; simply calling `MyClassName.this.finish()` , or something alike, should work just fine? The `onPostExecute()`, I believe, has UI scope.

Comment: My ASyncTask is in external class. Looks like Sunil's approach works.