# Finish the calling activity when AsyncTask completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-context

My calling activity:

```
public class Hello extends Activity {  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MyTask mt = new MyTask(this);
    mt.execute();
}
```

Now In MyTask (an external class):

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Context mContext;

public MyTask(Context context) {

    mContext = context;
}  

//doinbackground, etc

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    mContext.finish();

}
```

Other things are working as expected if I remove `mContext.finish()` above.
But if I'm calling `mContext.finish()` , I'm getting an error: `The method finish() is undefined for the type Context` (Eclipse doesn't show finish() when I write mContext. so that suggests I'm using finish() wrongly.)

What do I need to do to finish the calling activity `Hello` after `MyTask` completes the task

Comment: What if you write Hello.this.finish()?

Comment: @user370305: I tried that already but it says: `No enclosing instance of the type Hello is accessible in scope`

Answer (score 23):

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();
```

Would be the correct way to cast a `Context` to an `Activity` and call its `finish()` method. Not sure why you'd want to finish an `Activity` from an `AsyncTask` though

Comment: Many Thanks @MisterSquonk (and others who tried to help). Reason for which I needed this was that from an activity A, I was calling Activity B, in which I called the AsyncTask and I didn't need Activity B after the task was done, that's why I wanted to finish it as soon as the task is done.

Comment: Oops, it's not working and I'm getting a Run Time Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Answer (score 19):

What you can try to do instead of calling context.finish(), why don't you do a callback interface like this:

```
public interface TaskCallback{
void done();
}
```

Then you implement this into your Activity

```
public Hello extends Activity implements TaskCallback{

    .....BUNCH OF ACTIVITY CODE.....

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MyTask mt = new MyTask(this);
    mt.execute();
}

public void done() {
     finish();
}

}
```

And instead of having Context as a parameter you have TaskCallback

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private TaskCallback mCallback;

public MyTask(TaskCallback callback) {

    mCallback = callback;
}  

//doinbackground, etc

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    mCallback.done();

}
```

There you go, it gives you more flexibility to custom each implementation.

Comment: If instead of Context we pass TaskCallback, then I'm unable to do anything on the UI in MyTask like `new ProgressDialog(mContext);` which I was able to do previously

Comment: you still can cast the TaskCallback into a Context, or you can also implement a method for your progress aside from done(), another alternative is to cast a context as a Activity and check it with instanceof

Comment: Thank you. Works brilliantly. You forgot to notice that we have to create a new java file named as TaskCallback contained interface code, in our case, it will method "done". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same situation, then I do as follows:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Activity mActivity;
private Context mContext;

public MyTask(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
}  

//doinbackground, etc

protected void onPostExecute() {
    mActivity.finish();

}
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 2):

Define a method in your activity class like this:

```
public void FinishAfterAsyncTask()
{
   this.finish();
}
```

And call this method from the `OnPostExecute` method of the `AsynTask` class.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new private AsyncTask extended from your public one.

In this private AsyncTask you have access to the Activity stuff and you can override the onPostExecute method to finish it.

**Your truly AsyncTask**

```
public class MyPublicAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context context;
    public GetHorariosAsyncTask(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // prepare yourself for an async work
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do yout cool async stuff
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // you're finish, let's tell to user
    }
}
```

**Your Activity with private AsyncTask**

```
public class MyActivity  extends Activity {
    Activity mAct;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        mAct = this;
    }

    private class MyPrivateAsyncTask extends MyPublicAsyncTask {

        public MyPrivateAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // our async task is completed! let's take care of this activity
            mAct.finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Can you try

```
this.finish()
```

Seems like its because of calling it using mContext that it says undefined.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work as finish() can't be executed on an AsyncTask but only on an Activity. It's giving this error: `The method finish() is undefined for the type MyTask`