# How to kill activity after MyAsyncTask is done

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finish the calling activity when AsyncTask completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623823/finish-the-calling-activity-when-asynctask-completes)

I know that I have to use asyncTask for operations that take long like db writing.

However, one of my issues is how to tell My activity not close until operation is done.

Example:

I have Activity A that should do a DB insert when the user hit submit. So when user hit submit, I am creating an asyncTask to update the db. The problem is  I have it like

new MyAsyncTask().execute()
finish();

As a result, my activity is closing before the asyncTask is completed. How can I ensure that my activity stays open until MyAsyncTask is done processing

Thank you

Comment: why not just do a `finish` in the onPostExecute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `finish()` in `onPostExecute`() of async task.

Comment: shoooot! How did I not think about that! I am always under the impression that finish belongs in the activity code! Thanks a lot

Comment: It does, You can access finish() from inner class.And if your async task is seperate class you can still call finish by sending activity reference to there.