# How to hide ProgressBar and show ListView after 3 AsynchTasks have finished

Tags: android

in my application I need to show a circular ProgressBar until 3 AsynchTasks have finished.

I am not able to reach the result.

Please any help appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ArrayList<String> files=new ArrayList<String>();
public String mQuery=null;
public File root=Environment.getRootDirectory();
public ArrayAdapter<String> ad;
public ArrayList<String> queries= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(".prc",".mobi",".epub"));
public ProgressBar pb;
public  ListView lv;
public LinearLayout ll;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    pb =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
} 

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);

    for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){

        AddStringTask as= new AddStringTask();
        try {
            mQuery=queries.get(i);
            as.execute(Environment.getRootDirectory());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
    //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for(int i1=0;i1<files.size();i1++){
        ad.add(files.get(i1));
    }

    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String path =(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if((!path.endsWith(".prc"))) {
            Intent vi=new Intent();
            vi.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            vi.setData(Uri.parse("file://" +path));
            vi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(vi);
            }

            if((path.endsWith(".prc"))) {
                String bookID=path.substring(path.length()-19, path.length()-9);
                Intent vi=new Intent();
                vi.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                Uri file = Uri.parse("kindle://book/?action=open&book_id=AMZNID0/" + bookID + "/0/");
                vi.setData(file);
                vi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(vi);
                }
        }
    });

}

class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... root) {

        search(root[0]);

        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ll.invalidate();
    }
}
```

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MaintringTask ms = new MaintringTask();
    ms.execute();

class MaintringTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... root) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {

            AddStringTask as = new AddStringTask();
            try {
                mQuery = queries.get(i);
                as.execute(Environment.getRootDirectory()).get();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < files.size(); i1++) {
            ad.add(files.get(i1));
        }

        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(File... root) {
            search(root[0]);
            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably have a counter initialized with the number of task which you want to perform. The counter gets decremented when a `asyncTask` is complete and the `progressBar` is dismissed once the counter = 0. And you can check for the completion of each of the `asyncTask` and doing the decrement in the counter, the progress bar dismissal and so on in the onPostExecute for each of the `asyncTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method that will be called when each of three AsyncTask call on post execute and this method check if the three AsyncTask is finished for example this method:

```
private void methodName ()
{
   if(task1 && task2 && task3)
   {
    //execute the code ... hide the progress bar
   }
}
```

And on the post execute will be like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //AsyncTask one on post execute
        task1 == true;
        methodName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question and code correctly what you need to change is the way you hide the progress bar and display the view. The way your code is now will result in the bar being hidden and the list being displayed after the completion of every `AsyncTask`.

You need to have the code to hide the progress bar and display list called only once and to have this be after the last `AsyncTask` completes.

What you could potentially do is have a static [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) that you increment when an `AsyncTask` completes. Then, on the completion of each task, call a method that holds the code to hide the progress bar and show the list. However, this method only executes this code if the count mentioned is 3.

You can achieve this by using an interface to allow the task to call a method in the class that executed it, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623905/710641). Or you can do it via a static method in MainActivity.

Side note:
If you would like to have this behaviour extend to tasks that can run at any time, rather than using a preset value like 3, have another count the is incremented when tasks begin and in the method check if the number of tasks started is equal to the number of tasks completed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try dismissing a progress bar in UI thread

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 run(){
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.Gone)
     }
 }
```